# Awesomium decrease webview memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, awesomium

I am making a bot for browser games. I am using http://awesomium.com to connect to the page.
I use webview to display the page on a curstom form but the problem is, after long time, the awesomium_process reach 200k of memory usage and it keeps raising..
I don't know how can I decrease the memory usage.. (I can't use webcontrol because the injectmousemove doesn't cause effect on flash content in the webcontrol)

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Awesomium.Core;
using Awesomium.Windows.Forms;
using Awesomium.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ProBot
{
public partial class Explorer : UserControl
{

    private WebView webView;
    private ImageSurface surface;
    private WebSession session;
    public Explorer()
    {
        session = InitializeCoreAndSession();
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeView(WebCore.CreateWebView(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height, session));
    }

    #region Metodos

    private void InitializeView(WebView view)
    {
        if (view == null)
            return;

        surface = new ImageSurface();
        surface.Updated += OnSurfaceUpdated;

        webView = view;
        webView.Surface = surface;
        webView.Source = "http://google.com".ToUri();
        webView.FocusView();
    }

    private WebSession InitializeCoreAndSession()
    {
        if (!WebCore.IsInitialized)
            WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig() { LogLevel = LogLevel.Normal, ReduceMemoryUsageOnNavigation = true });

        // Build a data path string. In this case, a Cache folder under our executing directory.
        // - If the folder does not exist, it will be created.
        // - The path should always point to a writeable location.
        string dataPath = String.Format("{0}{1}Cache", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

        // Check if a session synchronizing to this data path, is already created;
        // if not, create a new one.
        session = WebCore.Sessions[dataPath] ??
            WebCore.CreateWebSession(dataPath, WebPreferences.Default);

        // The core must be initialized by now. Print the core version.
        Debug.Print(WebCore.Version.ToString());

        // Return the session.
        return session;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((surface != null) && (surface.Image != null))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(surface.Image, 0, 0);
        }
        else
            base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.IsRendering = (this.ClientSize.Width > 0) && (this.ClientSize.Height > 0);
        if (webView.IsRendering)
            webView.Resize(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectMouseMove(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectMouseDown(e.Button.GetMouseButton());
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectMouseUp(e.Button.GetMouseButton());
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectMouseWheel(e.Delta, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectKeyboardEvent(e.GetKeyboardEvent());
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectKeyboardEvent(e.GetKeyboardEvent(WebKeyboardEventType.KeyDown));
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        if ((webView == null) || (!webView.IsLive))
            return;

        webView.InjectKeyboardEvent(e.GetKeyboardEvent(WebKeyboardEventType.KeyUp));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Eventos
    private void OnSurfaceUpdated(object sender, SurfaceUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
            Invalidate(e.DirtyRegion.ToRectangle(), false); 
    }
    #endregion

    #region Publics

    private delegate void InstarMouseMoverCallback(int x, int y);
    public void InsertarMouseMover(int x, int y)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            InstarMouseMoverCallback method = InsertarMouseMover;
            Invoke(method, new object[] { x, y });
        }
        else
        {
            webView.InjectMouseMove(x, y);
        }
    }

    private delegate void InstarMouseClickIzquierdoCallback();
    public void InsertarMouseClickIzquierdo()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            InstarMouseClickIzquierdoCallback method = InsertarMouseClickIzquierdo;
            Invoke(method, new object[] {});
        }
        else
        {
            webView.InjectMouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
            webView.InjectMouseUp(MouseButton.Left);
        }
    }

    Bitmap captura;
    private delegate Bitmap CapturaCallback();
    public Bitmap Captura()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            CapturaCallback method = Captura;
            Invoke(method, new object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            captura = new Bitmap(surface.Image);
        }
        return captura;
    }

    private delegate void ReducirMemoriaCallback();
    public void ReducirMemoria()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            ReducirMemoriaCallback method = ReducirMemoria;
            Invoke(method, new object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            webView.ReduceMemoryUsage();
        }
    }

    private delegate void CerrarCoreCallback();
    public void CerrarCore()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            CerrarCoreCallback method = CerrarCore;
            Invoke(method, new object[] { });
        }
        else
        {
            WebCore.Shutdown();
        }

    }

    public void CambiarPagina(String pagina)
    {
        webView.Source = new Uri(pagina);
    }
    #endregion


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to improve the situation, but it also depends on what you're working with and how your game is built.

If you are using awesomium 1.7.4 you might consider reverting to Awesomium 1.7.3, memory usage in the new awesomium has gone up considerably.

You could use a memory profiler to see if you're creating any memory leaks that are affecting your memory usage.

When awesomium processes increase in size, one reason is because of javascript execution creating objects on the page, verify that you're not leaking memory in any javascript code you have setup.

Flash may also be leaking memory, verify that you're not leaking any memory there.

There are a lot of tools on the web for profiling these various components.  I've used ANTS for memory profiling of .NET and I found it very useful and informative.

The first step I would take if you're running 1.7.4 would be to try 1.7.3 as it can be a fairly simple change.  I recently (Yesterday as of this post actually) had to move my code base back to 1.7.3 because of memory issues in 1.7.4   I'm sure these problems will be fixed, but I needed stability now.

Comment: Will reverting to version 1.7.3 remove any major features of Awesomium (multi-threading, javascript callbacks, etc.)?

Comment: Reverting to 1.7.3 will remove the Mutli-threading added in 1.7.4    however synchronous JavaScript callbacks have been part of Awesomium for a very long time.